# weird UITabBar color inconsistency in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm using iOS 7's `tintColor` and `barTintColor` properties to color my `UITabBar` with this code in a subclass of UITabBarController:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:1]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

On three screens, the color is what I want it to be (only two images illustrating this):

[image: home screen]
[image: feedback screen]

One one screen, the color is weirdly lighter. This screen is a `UIWebView`.

[image: webview screen]

Then on a fourth screen, the color is SUPER-light. This screen is the only one to use a storyboard--the rest are all done programmatically.

[image: settings screen]

What am I doing wrong? Do the fact that the misbehaving screens are a `UIWebView` and a storyboard have anything to do with why they're misbehaving? And how do I fix them? I've fiddled with the alpha of the bar but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're seeing tab bar translucency...i.e. the background view is bleeding through and being blurred.  If you want to disable this, you can do:

```
[tabBar setTranslucent:NO]
```

on your tab-bar.

On your top two images, its not clear to me if the underlying view controller view is edge-to-edge, i.e. your top two images *should* look like the fourth one since both have pink backgrounds.  Anyhow, setTranslucent:NO should make them all look like the top image.

Comment: Thanks--but the problem is that I'm using not a `UITabBar` but a `UITabBarController`, which doesn't seem to have a translucent property. Or am I wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try     `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];`?   Keep in mind the the `UITabBarController` is not a `UIView`... it's an object that, among other responsibilities, manages a `UITabBar`.  You have to drill into the `.tabBar` property to make modifications.

Comment: Hunh--that did it! But I thought the `tabBar` property was read-only?

Comment: From the documentation: "@property(nonatomic,readonly) UITabBar *tabBar

You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view throws an exception. To configure the items for your tab bar interface, you should instead assign one or more custom view controllers to the viewControllers property....

The tab bar view provided by this property is only for situations where you want to display an action sheet using the showFromTabBar: method of the UIActionSheet class."

Answer (score 1):

You can also uncheck "Translucent" at the Attributes Inspector:
[image]