# UItabbar becomes dull while setting images on it in iphone

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am creating an app which uses Tab bar controller. While I am setting images on it my images is looking little bit dull. I have referred stack link - [weird UITabBar color inconsistency in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905324/weird-uitabbar-color-inconsistency-in-ios7) and also follows as link shows an answer by setting translucent property to No, but still it looking dull. One more thing is that while i'm setting translucent property to No my view which I have loaded in tabbar's root view controller is showing slightly up from its current position and again i'm set translucent property to no the view is being set is it should be.I am giving you below tabbar image which is being appeared in my screen -
[image]

I want to look my tab bar as below  -

[image]

how could i achieve it?please provide me proper guidence. Your help will be appreciated.